# Center content in Vuetify project / Grid system

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am starting learning Vue.js and I got a problem with understanding Vuetify's grid system. Now I want to center that content to the center. I've read docs and tried for many ways, but positioning elements it is still random, I would say.

Can anybody explain me `v-content`, `v-layout` and `v-flex`?

Here's code.

```
   <template>
    <v-container>
     <v-layout text-center>
      <v-flex xs4 >
       <v-img
        :src="require('../assets/logo.svg')"
        class="my-3"
        contain
        height="200"
       >
       </v-img>
       <v-text-field v-model="newPrice" placeholder="Add price"></v-text-field>
       <v-btn @click="addPrices">Add price </v-btn>
       <v-text-field v-model="newVolume" placeholder="Add volume"></v-text-field>
       <v-btn @click="AddVolume">Add volume </v-btn>
      </v-flex>
     </v-layout>
    </v-container>
   </template>
   <script>
   export default {
    name: 'MainPage',
    data () {
     return {
      prices: [],
      volumes: [],
      newPrice: '',
      newVolume: ''
    }
   },
    methods: {
     addPrices () {
      this.prices.push(this.newPrice)
     },
    addVolume () {
      this.volumes.push(this.newVolume)
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So vuetify's grid system takes advantage of [CSS flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). `v-container` determines the spacing around and between elements; `v-layout` determines the flex axis/direction/order of the elements, and `v-flex` determines how big the elements will be in the 12-point grid system.

To center something, try the below:
`<v-layout row justify-center></v-layout>`
This is equivalent to:

```
.layout {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center; 
}
```

There is no prop in the `v-layout` component named `text-center` so I'm guessing that's why it's not centering.